# Can I use "prefer" with "over"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Based on [Cambridge site](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/prefer), it is obviously more common to use "prefer + to" or "prefer + rather than"

> I prefer football **rather than** computer games.
>
> I prefer tea **to** coffee

**I have a habit to use "prefer" + "over", and I wonder whether it is grammatically wrong or unnatural:**

> I prefer tea over coffee

Comment: We usually use “to” with “prefer” when comparing two things. “Prefer over” is acceptable but “prefer to” is more common. You could replace “rather than” with “to” in your first sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which one: **I'd prefer to drink tea rather than drink coffee / I'd prefer to drink tea rather than coffee / I'd prefer to drink tea to coffee**?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102991/which-one-id-prefer-to-drink-tea-rather-than-drink-coffee-id-prefer-to-dr) See also [How “would prefer” & “would rather” used in combination with “rather than” when refer to another person?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139598/) and [“prefer to” Vs “prefer + rather than”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147547/), among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use them both. However **"prefer" + "over"** is fairly new usage compared to **"prefer" + "to"**. I suggest you to check the following website which gives in-depth information about your question:

https://jakubmarian.com/prefer-to-or-prefer-over-which-preposition/